# React js functional component state context issue with asyc call one after another

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am facing react state context issue.

I have a simple react functional component, When i update the state of component two times.
The last call of state is keeping the last context of state ( What it was before ).

Note: The second call which changes the state is async in nature. ( React keep the state changes in queue if they are synchronous in nature but in my case due to async operation it flushes. )

And due to functional component it is creating closure so it is not getting the latest state value.

Sample code.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const asyncCall = setStateFn => {
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setStateFn({
      error2: `Error4 ${new Date()}`
    });
  });
};

export default function App() {
  const [obj, setObj] = useState({
    error1: `Error1 ${new Date()}`,
    error2: `Error2 ${new Date()}`
  });

  const setStateFn = newState => {
    setObj({ ...obj, ...newState });
  };

  const onClick = () => {
    setStateFn({ error1: `Error3 ${new Date()}` });
    asyncCall(setStateFn);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      {JSON.stringify(obj)}
      <br />
      <button type="button" onClick={onClick}>
        Change State
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Expectation: "error1" key should have the " Error3 updated New Date "

Current Result : "error1" key has the " Error1 last Date "

You can also see the code on codesandbox

[Sample Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-star-yssyl)

Please suggest solution for that.

Comment: I don't see anything asynchronous in your code apart from the `onclick` handler. You know that promises don't create asynchronous functions don't you? Promises is just a design pattern for handling asynchronous functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use updater function instead of using state variable, that will fix your problem.

change your setStateFn to

```
const setStateFn = newState => {
  setObj(prevObj => ({ ...prevObj, ...newState }));
};
```

Problem was when your async function was trying access obj from your function it had old values so it was merging with wrong state value.

[image: Edit little-morning-x429g]

Comment: Thanks Amit for providing solution.

One more way i found to fix it. Using "useReducer".

Here you can see it.  https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-brattain-f99ew   It also solves 
scope context issue.